# MGTwitterEngine yajl error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4

I'm trying to get MGTwitterEngine to work for the iPhone SDK. But getting the following error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_yajl_alloc", referenced from:
      -[MGTwitterYAJLParser initWithJSON:delegate:connectionIdentifier:requestType:responseType:URL:deliveryOptions:] in MGTwitterYAJLParser.o
  "_yajl_parse", referenced from:
      -[MGTwitterYAJLParser initWithJSON:delegate:connectionIdentifier:requestType:responseType:URL:deliveryOptions:] in MGTwitterYAJLParser.o
  "_yajl_get_error", referenced from:
      -[MGTwitterYAJLParser initWithJSON:delegate:connectionIdentifier:requestType:responseType:URL:deliveryOptions:] in MGTwitterYAJLParser.o
  "_yajl_free_error", referenced from:
      -[MGTwitterYAJLParser initWithJSON:delegate:connectionIdentifier:requestType:responseType:URL:deliveryOptions:] in MGTwitterYAJLParser.o
  "_yajl_free", referenced from:
      -[MGTwitterYAJLParser initWithJSON:delegate:connectionIdentifier:requestType:responseType:URL:deliveryOptions:] in MGTwitterYAJLParser.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your build target, you need to exclude the files whose names contain "YAJL".

If you're using Xcode 4, this should be accessible in your target's Build Phases, under "Compile Sources".